# How to always return the result of a query from hibernate despite an error present?

Tags: java, hibernate

### My Case

I have two entities, `student` and `school` which are structured as follows:

```java
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school")
    private School school 
}
```

```java
@Table(name = "School")
public class School
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;
}
```

The following are the two views values:

**Student**

| id | name | school |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Albert | MCD |
| B | Kevin | LSU |
| C | Jack | NY |
| D | Robert | CA |
| E | Samuel |  |

**School**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| MCD | Mich |
| LSU | Los |
| CA | Car |

So when in hibernate i'm doing a simple `select * from Student`, it throws an error because the 'NY' id does not exist in the school table.

(To be precise, it throws `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: No row with the given identifier exists`)

### Final Goal

My goal is to bypass the error that is thrown an still return the correct entity (So Albert, Kevin, Robert, Samuel)

Comment: Why do you not have a foreign key constraint and the data in the table? Sounds like your design is bakwards.

Comment: I did not make the original software so unfortunately I can only adapt to the particular cases I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a semi-scalable solution I changed the initial view and returned `NULL` if it is not present. The change makes the query a little slower but avoids doing one query per element (that would make the environment much slower).

### Before

```sql
SELECT  ST.ID AS id,
        ST.NAME AS name,
        ST.ID AS school
FROM Student ST
```

### Afther

```sql
SELECT  ST.ID AS id,
        ST.NAME AS name,
        SC.ID AS school
FROM Student ST
LEFT JOIN School SC
    ON ST.SCHOOL = SC.ID
```

### Post release notes

Also for compound ids, the best solution seems to be a `case when` with all the various combinations.

Keep in mind that this is a very small example to understand the logic behind the problem, adding many tables in `left join` will make the cost of the query increases significantly. However, remains the best compromise after a week of trials and proposed solutions.

Comment: So basically my answer then? Plus some extra de-structuring which wasn't present in the original post

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` on top of School in `Student` class. As mentioned by Davide d'Alto on his answer, there's no `NY` in table `School` so an exception will be risen by default.

Fixing the database should be the proper answer but sometimes it's not possible or might have other undesired consequences on other applications.

In this case, when annotating with `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` the value will be set to `null` in case it's not found.

```
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school")
    private School school 
}
```

More info:

[Baeldung - Hibernate EntityNotFoundException](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entitynotfoundexception)

[JavaDoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html)

Comment: I didn't know that kind of annotation, could you link in your answer the documentation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added the documentation. I had to learn this the hard way. I'm working on an application that data is modified by another and the developer had the bad habit of setting the FK_ID to 0 instead of null if the relationship is empty.

Comment: I have done some tests and it seems to work, but there is a big problem .. all my entities have been found to be 500% slower which is way too much.

Comment: `@NotFound` changes the fetching behavior to `FetchType.EAGER`. That’s even the case if you explicitly set `FetchType.LAZY` in your association mapping

Answer (score 2):

You said that you're using a simple `SELECT * FROM Student` query, which means you are using custom queries.

In your case, you should be able to change it to `SELECT * FROM Student St LEFT JOIN School Sc ON Sc.ID = St.School;`.

What that should do is load all of the records in one query and any student records that don't have a matching school should return null for the `School` attribute on the `Student` class.

Side Note: When working with relationships and JPA, if it's a simple relationship like this, you can use joins to ensure everything is loaded in one query, rather than JPA loading all of the parent entities and then issuing a query for each of those to fetch the child entities, so it can have quite the performance improvement.

Comment: That's not a bad answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Using a `left join`, the wrong values ​​are retrieved (and so the exception is thrown). I also thought about using an `inner join` but I would end up excluding all the elements that do not have that column valued.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1: handle exception in getter**

One approach that can be used is to modify your getter method using static methods: [Hibernate.isInitialized](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#isInitialized(java.lang.Object)) and [Hibernate.initialize](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize(java.lang.Object)) and handle `EntityNotFoundException`

```java
    public School getSchool() {
        if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(school)) {
            try {
                Hibernate.initialize(school);
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
                school = null;
            }
        }
        return school;
    }
```

```java
@Table(name = "Student")
@Entity
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school")
    private School school;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public School getSchool() {
        if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(school)) {
            try {
                Hibernate.initialize(school);
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
                school = null;
            }
        }
        return school;
    }

    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: load child entity via separate repository**

Remove `ManyToOne` relation from your entity

```java
@Table(name = "Student")
@Entity
public class Student
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "school")
    private String school;
}
```

Create separate repository for `School` entity with optional loading by ID

```java
@Repository
public interface SchoolRepository extends JpaRepository<School, String> {
    Optional<School> findById(String id);
}
```

Use `SchoolRepository` repository for loading entity in required places

```java
        List<Student> students = studentRepository.findStudents();
        Student student = students.get(2);

        if (student.getSchool() != null) {
            School school = schoolRepository.findById(student.getSchool()).orElse(null);
        }
```

**Solution 3: [@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html) with [LEFT JOIN FETCH](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)**

Define ignore `@NotFound` annotation

```java
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school")
    private School school
```

Rewrite your query for loading `Student` entities. Use [LEFT JOIN FETCH](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins), it allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select. It significantly improves performance. `Student` and `School` entities will be initialized by one query.

```java
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {

    @Query(value = "select s from Student s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.school sc")
    List<Student> findStudents();
}
```

The main idea of that solution is that you will not have many EGEAR queries for initialization child entities, but only one and `@NotFound` will skip exception.

Hibernate will generate one batch query:

```sql
    select
        student0_.id as id1_34_0_,
        school1_.id as id1_31_1_,
        student0_.name as name2_34_0_,
        student0_.school as school3_34_0_,
        school1_.state as state2_31_1_ 
    from
        student student0_ 
    left outer join
        school school1_ 
            on student0_.school=school1_.id
```

And the second query just for one missed `School` entity to ensure that it is not present in DB

```java
    select
        school0_.id as id1_31_0_,
        school0_.state as state2_31_0_ 
    from
        school school0_ 
    where
        school0_.id=?
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will thoroughly analyze your answer and test every solution you have for me! I immediately got a question for the method number 3, if there was a list of entities within the `Student` entity. For an example a `List<Subject>`, how would the second query behave? Would you go to create a query for each individual sub-entity to verify its existence?

Comment: As I understand your question correctly. You mean that instead of ManyToOne relation you will have OneToMany on parent entity. In this case Solution 3 is not acceptable. LEFT JOIN FETCH for OneToMany relation will give you duplication of parent records it will influance on performance.