# How to handle EntityNotFoundException during Hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I'm working on an application where we need to query for a collection of entities using hibernate and then perform some indexing on the results. Unfortunately, the database the application is querying from does not enforce foreign key constraints on all associations, so the application needs to handle potentially broken references.

Currently, the code responsible for doing the query looks like this:

```
private List<? extends Entity> findAll(Class entity, Integer startIndex, Integer pageSize)
        throws EntityIndexingServiceException {
    try {
        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery("select entity from " + entity.getName() + " entity order by entity.id desc");
        if (startIndex != null && pageSize != null) {
            return query.setFirstResult(startIndex).setMaxResults(pageSize).getResultList();
        } else {
            return query.getResultList();
        }
    } 
    catch (Throwable e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        log.warn(sw.toString());
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that bad data in any of the results will result in the whole page of data being skipped. So if I'm using this method to get a list of objects to index, none of the query results will be included in the indexing even though only one or two were invalid.

I know Hibernate has a @NotFound annotation, but that comes with it's own side-effects like forced eager loading that I would rather avoid. If possible, I want to exclude invalid entities from the results, not load them in a broken state.

So the question then is how can I handle this query in such a way that invalid results (those that cause an EntiyNotFoundException to be thrown) are excluded from the return values without also throwing out the 'good' data?

Comment: If you aren't using a homebrewn logging framework `log.warn(e)` should do the same as your `log.warn(sw.toString())`.

Comment: Probably will be useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620571/how-to-always-return-the-result-of-a-query-from-hibernate-despite-an-error-prese/72708114#72708114

Comment: @ Eugene That is some good info, but I don't think I can use any of those solutions. The entities are getting loaded by Hibernate as part of the call to getResultList(). I can't use a getter or a custom respository since I would never have an opportunity to make those call before the exception gets thrown.